# how to save multiple checkbox values in rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox

I'm doing fixeddeposit project, in opening account page (i.e.,) in _form. I'm having checkbox to select the deposit amount using [javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/H4d7W/). Where deposit amount's datatype is float. It add the value on that page only, when i am trying to hit the submit button it shows the folowing error message

> undefined method `to_f' for ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "100000", "0", "0"]:Array

**** my _form.html.erb****

```
<tr>
  <th><%= f.label :click_your_deposit_amount %></th>    
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> 
    <%= f.check_box :depamt, {:multiple => "true"}, 500 %>500

    <%= f.check_box :depamt, {:multiple => "true"}, 1000 %>1000

    <%= f.check_box :depamt, {:multiple => "true"}, 2000 %>2000

    <%= f.check_box :depamt, {:multiple => "true"}, 3000 %>3000

    <%= f.check_box :depamt, {:multiple => "true"}, 4000 %>4000

    <%= f.check_box :depamt, {:multiple => "true"}, 5000 %>5000

    <%= f.check_box :depamt, {:multiple => "true"}, 10000 %>10000

    <%= f.check_box :depamt, {:multiple => "true"}, 50000 %>50000

    <%= f.check_box :depamt, {:multiple => "true"}, 100000 %>100000

    <%= f.check_box :depamt, {:multiple => "true"}, 500000 %>500000

    <%= f.check_box :depamt, {:multiple => "true"}, 1000000 %>1000000
  </td>
</tr>    
<tr>
  <td>
    <span id="span"></span>
    <div>Total Deposit Amount: <span id="amt"> </span></div>
  </td>
</tr>

<script>
  $('input:checkbox').change(function(){ 
    var total = 0;
    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
      total+=parseInt($(this).val());
      $('#amt').html(total)
      }); 
    });
</script>
```

here is my controller

**fds_controller.rb**

```
 class FdsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @fd = Fd.new
  end

  def create

    @fd = Fd.new(params[:fd])
    if @fd.save
      flash[:success] = "FD Account Opened Successfully!"
      redirect_to fds_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Couldn't Open FD"  
      render  'new'
    end

  end

end
```

I dono how to store the checked values in my database(sqlite3).

Kindly help me to solve this issue.

-Thanks... :)

Comment: Could you please print params[:fd] in the method and post the log here?

Comment: @visnu: you mean heroku logs?. Sorry, i'm new to programming and ruby on rails.

Comment: No. Are you running the rails app locally(YOur Machine)?

Comment: yes. but, i dono how to see the local log... :(

Comment: in rails server it shows:   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1.7ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `to_f' for ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "100000", "0", "0"]:Array):
  app/controllers/fds_controller.rb:7:in `new'
  app/controllers/fds_controller.rb:7:in `create'

Comment: run "tail -f log\development.log" command in your terminal

Comment: "to_f" doesn't support array class

Comment: it shows:     tail: cannot open `logdevelopment.log' for reading: No such file or directory

Comment: You are trying to convert array into float. So it is raising error. Please iterate the array then convert it into float.

Comment: try `tail -f log/development.log` (forward slash, not back slash...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to call the `.to_f` method on an `Array`. You could call that method on items in the array, but not the array itself:

```
new_array = my_array.map(&:to_f)
```

This should convert all the items to floats and set this as a new array.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do is create a "depamt" serialized column for Fds (typically a text column is used in the database). ActiveRecord will automatically persist and fetch Array values for you. See the documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord%3a%3aBase-label-Saving+arrays,+hashes,+and+other+non-mappable+objects+in+text+columns) for examples of configuring your model.